# How do I disable desktop notifications from popping over fullscreen flash/regular videos?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I love the new desktop notifications feature in google chrome and would not want to disable it. However, what I would like to disable is notifications from popping up when I am watching a movie in fullscreen or watching a video on youtube in fullscreen.

Is there any way I can do that? It is very annoying to have all these notifications pop up while watching a movie.

Google Chrome version - 10.0.648.127 (Official Build 76697): Operating System - Ubuntu 10.10. Or is there a cool linux workaround possible? : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has fixed this! Now all the notifications pop up one after the other after you go out of full screen.